# RAISERROR - differences in SQLException behaviour in Java Client

Tags: java, sql-server, sqlexception, raiserror

I'm seeing differences in behaviour in how Java handles SQL Server errors thrown by `RAISERROR`, depending upon what the actual error is, in that:

- Unique Constraint Violation: The SQL Exception is trapped and handled by the Java Catch block
- Divide by Zero: The SQL Exception is not trapped

To demonstrate:

**1. Stored Procedure: uspTestRE**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE demo.uspTestRE (
  @inKey    VARCHAR(5),    --Primary Key value in TestRE table
  @inDBZ    VARCHAR(1)     --Y/N flag to trigger Divide By Zero error
)
AS
BEGIN

  SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON;

  BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

      --Insert record into TestRE table
      INSERT INTO TestRE (tREKey) VALUES (@inKey);

      --Trigger DBZ error
      IF @inDBZ = 'Y'
       BEGIN
         SELECT 1/0;
       END;

    --Transaction is in a state to be committed
    IF (XACT_STATE())=1
      BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
      END;
  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE
      @errorMessage  NVARCHAR(MAX) = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
      @errorState    INT           = ERROR_STATE(),
      @errorSeverity INT           = ERROR_SEVERITY();

    --Transaction is uncommitable so rollback
    IF (XACT_STATE()) = -1
      BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
      END;

    RAISERROR(@errorMessage,@errorSeverity,@errorState);

    RETURN 23;
  END CATCH

END;
```

When executing the SP from SQLCMD, it generates the following error messages:

Test 1: Key Violation

```
Msg 50000, Level 14, State 1, Server WW-HV5FQV2, Procedure demo.uspTestRE, Line 44
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__TestRE__0FEE01A3EEF4E2AE'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TestRE'. The duplicate key value is (UKV).
```

Test 2: Divide by Zero

```
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Server WW-HV5FQV2, Procedure demo.uspTestRE, Line 42
Divide by zero error encountered.
```

i.e. expected behaviour for both.

However, my Java program doesn't give the same behaviour.

**2. Java Program: uspTestRE.java**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;

public class uspTestRE {

    // Connect to DEMO_INST database as svcDemoInst Login
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String connectionUrl =
                "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;"
                + "database=DEMO;"
                + "user=svcDemoLogin;"
                + "password=Demo;"
                + "trustServerCertificate=true;"
                + "loginTimeout=30;";

        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        CallableStatement cstmt = null;

        try {cstmt = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl).prepareCall("{? = call demo.uspTestRE(?,?)}");
             int i = 0;
             cstmt.registerOutParameter(++i,java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

             cstmt.setString(++i,args[0]);
             cstmt.setString(++i,args[1]);
             cstmt.execute();

             int returnCode = cstmt.getInt(1);
             System.out.println("Success: Stored Procedure Return Status: " + returnCode);
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
              System.out.println("Error Code: " + e.getErrorCode() +", Error Message: "+e.getMessage());
              // e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the same test cases here, I get the following:

Test 1: Key Violation (Behaves as Expected)

```
C:\>java uspTestRE UKV N
Error Code: 50000, Error Message: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__TestRE__0FEE01A3EEF4E2AE'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TestRE'. The duplicate key value is (UKV).
```

Test 2: Divide by Zero (Does not get trapped)

```
C:\>java uspTestRE DBV Y
Success: Stored Procedure Return Status: 23
```

Can anyone explain to me why the Divide By Zero error - which is being trapped in SQL Server and handled in the SP Catch block - is not being trapped by the Java code?

The only differences I can see between the 2 errors is that the Divide by Zero error is Severity 16.

Comment: That looks like it should be an issue here: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues

Answer (score 1):

Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/7297700/david-browne-microsoft

I started to post the Github issue and one of the outputs they request is a JDBC trace.

When I did this and compared the 2 trace outputs for:

1. Unique Key Violation
2. Divide By Zero error

the following lines were present for the Divide By Zero test case:

- **Jun 10, 2020 5:28:50 PM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet**
- **FINE: SQLServerResultSet:1 created by (SQLServerCallableStatement:1)**

Having read in another post that RAISERROR behaves differently when the SP returns a resultset (unintentionally in my case), I changed the following code in the **uspTestRE** Stored Procedure:

```
IF @inDBZ = 'Y'
  BEGIN
    SELECT 1/0;
  END;
```

to

```
IF @inDBZ = 'Y'
  BEGIN
    SET @dbz = 1/0;
  END;
```

This solved my problem.

Now, I just need to work out what changes to make to trap Errors where Results Sets are returned in the Stored Procedure

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'set nocount on' instead of changing select to set